# Неверный json формат в ответе iikoCloud API

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

Столкнулся с проблемой при получении организаций с помощью API.

Код php запроса с использованием curl:

```
$ch = curl_init();

$availOrganizationsVars = [
'organizationIds' => ['null'],
'returnAdditionalInfo' => true,
'includeDisabled' => true,
'returnExternalData' => ['null']
];

$vars = json_encode($availOrganizationsVars);
$headers = [
    "Authorization: Bearer ".$token,
    "Content-Type: application/json"
];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api-ru.iiko.services/api/1/organizations");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $vars); // Post Fields
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

Сервер отдает ошибку:

"errorDescription": "Body has invalid JSON format.", "error": "INVALID_BODY_JSON_FORMAT"

пробовал разные варианты:

1. посылать пустой объект в json

   $empty = json_decode ("{}");
   $vars= json_encode($empty);
2. вариант где null не строчное значение

   $availOrganizationsVars = [
   'organizationIds' => [null],
   'returnAdditionalInfo' => true,
   'includeDisabled' => true,
   'returnExternalData' => [null]
   ];

   $vars = json_encode($availOrganizationsVars);
3. вариант без массива

   $availOrganizationsVars = [
   'organizationIds' => null,
   'returnAdditionalInfo' => true,
   'includeDisabled' => true,
   'returnExternalData' => null
   ];

   $vars = json_encode($availOrganizationsVars);

и т.д.

При это, аналогичный запрос выше, на получение токена авторизации работает как должно:

```
$logIn = ['apiLogin' => '#####'];
$vars = json_encode($logIn);


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api-ru.iiko.services/api/1/access_token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $vars); // Post Fields
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = [
    "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8"
];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$server_output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

пример из документации:
https://skr.sh/sOw42IFljdJ

а вот мой json, который я отправляю в теле запроса:

```
{
"organizationIds":[
"null"
],
"returnAdditionalInfo":true,
"includeDisabled":true,
"returnExternalData":[
"null"
]
}
```